# a fail-safe way to upload via HTTP

Tags: http, curl

I use curl to upload zip files to Nexus. Recently it failed, but my ant build continued because the exit code was 0. So I added the --fail flag. However,

> This method is not fail-safe and there are occasions where non-successful response codes will slip through, especially when authentication is involved (response codes 401 and 407).

So how can I get a fail-safe method to do this, with curl or anything else?